# Calculate TPR and FPR of a binary classifier for roc curve in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, roc

I was trying to calculate the True positive rate and false positive rate  and then plot the roc curve by hand, since I wanted to check the roc curve I got from sklearn.metrics roc_curve function.
But the roc curve of fpr(on x-axis) vs tpr(on y axis) I'm getting seems like the axes have been interchanged.
I'm doing a gradient descent binary classifier with two labels positive and negative. The relevant portion of the tensorflow code for the tpr, fpr calculation is given below:

```
prediction=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X,w)+b)
pred_pos= prediction.eval(feed_dict={X: x_pos})
pred_neg= prediction.eval(feed_dict={X: x_neg})
tpr=[]
fpr=[]
for j in range(100):
    pos=0
    neg=0
    n=j/100.
    for i in range(0,len(pred_pos)):
            if(pred_pos[i,1]>=n):
                pos+=1
            if(pred_neg[i,1]>=n):
                neg+=1
    tpr.append(pos/len(x_pos))
    fpr.append(neg/len(x_neg))

f= open('output.txt','wb')
arr=np.array([fpr,tpr])
arr=arr.T          
np.savetxt(f,arr,fmt=['%e','%e'])    
f.close()
```

I'm then plotting from the text file using gnuplot with fpr(x axis) and tpr(y axis), and I'm getting the plot attached. 
[image: roc curve fpr vs tpr]This is certainly not right. Why is this so? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems reasonable; it really does look like you've swapped positives and negatives somewhere.  Try outputting tpr and fpr to the terminal to make sure tpr is higher; if it is then the problem must be in your code for drawing the graph.  Also note that you have fpr first in `arr=np.array([fpr,tpr])`.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for your comment. Yes, I tried outputting that to the terminal, and tpr is lower than fpr. So that explains the graph. But I tried the same code for another network involving cnn and the roc curve looks just fine! tpr being greater than fpr. So I wonder what's wrong with this particular problem

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem with the code.
Instead of `if(pred_pos[i,1]>=n):` it should be `if(pred_pos[i,0]>=n):`(similarly for the pred_neg),
and then it gives the right values for fpr and tpr, with tpr being greater.
This was because the labelling of the data was done as [1,0] for positives and [0,1] for negatives. So the determining bit was at the 0th position of the prediction array.